# Helps with sprite spawn, sprite collision and score display

Tags: python, pygame

I need a bit of help regarding the spawn of the ball/player sprite and the collision between the ball/player and the enemy. I wanted to know how to change the spawn of the player/ball to the middle of the bottom. Also when the player hits the enemy, are you able to show me how to pause the game and display an image. I was also wondering if anyone knows how to display values on the .

```
import random
import pygame


class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        # self.image = pygame.image.load('basketball.png').convert_alpha()
        # self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (100, 100))
        self.image = pygame.Surface((100, 100)).convert_alpha()
        self.image.fill((160, 70, 0))
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 100, 100)
        self.speed_x = 0
        self.speed_y = 0
        self.radiusx = 0
        self.radiusy = 100
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)

    def update(self, screen_rect):  # Pass a rect with the size of the screen.
        self.x += self.speed_x
        self.y += self.speed_y
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x, self.y)
        if not screen_rect.contains(self.rect):
            # Clamp the rect if it's outside of the screen.
            self.rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)
            self.x, self.y = self.rect.topleft

    def render(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)


class Goal(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        # self.image = pygame.image.load('goal.png').convert_alpha()
        # self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (220, 220))
        self.image = pygame.Surface((220, 220)).convert_alpha()
        self.image.fill((60, 80, 110))
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 220, 220)

    def render(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)


class Ring(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        # self.image = pygame.image.load('ring.png').convert_alpha()
        # self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (400, 400))
        self.image = pygame.Surface((400, 400)).convert_alpha()
        self.image.fill((60, 180, 110))
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 400, 400)
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)

    def render(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)


class Baddie(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        # self.image = pygame.image.load().convert_alpha()
        # self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (220, 220))
        self.image = pygame.Surface((90, 90)).convert_alpha()
        self.image.fill((250, 50, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def render(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))


def main():
    width = 1200
    height = 722

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # Add a clock to limit the frame rate.
    pygame.display.set_caption('Basketball Shootout')
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)

    badtimer = 100
    badtimer1 = 0
    badguys = [[640, 100]]

    # court = pygame.image.load('halfcourt.jpg')
    # court = pygame.transform.scale(court, (1200, 722))
    court = pygame.Surface((1200, 722))
    court.fill((30, 30, 30))
    basketball = Ball(50, 50)
    goal = Goal(487, 0)
    ring = Ring(400, 400)
    # The player is not needed since the `basketball` is already
    # the playable ball instance.
    # player = Ball  # Just remove this line.

    # badguyimg1 = pygame.image.load("wpierdol.png")
    # badguyimg1 = pygame.transform.scale(badguyimg1, (100, 100))
    # badguyimg2 = pygame.image.load("bad_guy2.gif")
    # badguyimg2 = pygame.transform.scale(badguyimg2, (100, 100))
    # badguyimg3 = pygame.image.load("bad_guy3.gif")
    # badguyimg3 = pygame.transform.scale(badguyimg3, (100, 100))
    badguyimg1 = pygame.Surface((90, 90))
    badguyimg1.fill((60, 50, 210))
    badguyimg2 = pygame.Surface((90, 90))
    badguyimg2.fill((250, 50, 210))
    badguyimg3 = pygame.Surface((90, 90))
    badguyimg3.fill((250, 50, 130))
    badlist = [badguyimg1, badguyimg2, badguyimg3]

    score = 0  # The score variable was missing.

    stop_game = False

    while not stop_game:
        # Event handling.
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                stop_game = True
            # Either set the speed here or increment the `basketball.y`
            # in the while loop with `pygame.key.get_pressed`.
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    basketball.speed_y = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    basketball.speed_y = 5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    basketball.speed_x = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    basketball.speed_x = 5
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                # Stop the ball.
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    basketball.speed_y = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    basketball.speed_y = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and basketball.speed_x < 0:
                    basketball.speed_x = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and basketball.speed_x > 0:
                    basketball.speed_x = 0

        # Don't call get_pressed in the event loop (for every event).
        # pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        # if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
        #     basketball.y -= 5
        # elif pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        #     basketball.y += 5
        # if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:  # if not elif, to separate vertical and horizontal movement.
        #     basketball.x -= 5
        # elif pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        #     basketball.x += 5

        # Updating.
        basketball.update(screen_rect)
        badtimer -= 1

        point = pygame.sprite.collide_mask(basketball, ring)  # Use basketball not player.
        if point:
            # The score will be incremented continually.
            score = score + 1
            print(score)

        # Update the bad guys.
        if badtimer == 0:
            badguys.append([1040, random.randint(50,430)])
            badtimer = 100-(badtimer1*2)
        if badtimer1 >= 35:
            badtimer1 = 35
        else:
            badtimer1 += 5

        # You can `enumerate` the badguys list to get the index
        # and the item at the same time.
        for index, badguy in enumerate(badguys[:]):
            if badguy[0] < -64:
                # Don't modify a list while you're iterating over it.
                # Iterate over a slice copy: badguys[:]
                badguys.pop(index)
            badguy[0] -= 7

        # Drawing.
        screen.blit(court, (0,0))

        text = font.render(
            'Dodge the other team to get to the goal!',
            True, (0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(text, (430, 630))
        goal.render(screen)
        # You forgot to render the ring.
        ring.render(screen)

        for badguy in badguys:
            screen.blit(badguyimg1, badguy)  # The `dest`ination arg was missing.

        basketball.render(screen)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)  # Limit the frame rate to 60 FPS.

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time.

Comment: Here's a simple way to pause a game with another function that contains a second while loop: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46843041/6220679 And this answer explains how you can render and blit text: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20842987/6220679

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To spawn the ball at the bottom of the screen, you can use the `midbottom` coordinates of the `screen_rect`, pass them to the `__init__` method of the ball,

```
# In the main function.
start_x, start_y = screen_rect.midbottom
basketball = Ball(start_x, start_y)
```

and then assign the coords to the `midbottom` attribute of the rect in the `Ball` class:

```
class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((100, 100)).convert_alpha()
        self.image.fill((160, 70, 0))
        # Pass the midbottom position as an argument to `get_rect`.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom=(x, y))
        # Alternatively.
        # self.rect.midbottom = x, y

        # Set the x and y attributes afterwards.
        self.x = self.rect.x
        self.y = self.rect.y
```